# lookup field values in another field

Tags: python, pandas

this df :

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    
    Open_Time_s=['2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00']
    intersect=[np.nan,np.nan,'intersect_2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','intersect_2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00']
    
    df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Open Time':intersect,'intersect':intersect},orient='index').transpose()
df['LEVEL']=np.nan
```

I need to return match indexes.
For some unknown reason, the search is not working.
Maybe the reason is in the data format ?

code:

```
print(df3[df3['Open Time']==df3['intersect'].str.replace(r'intersect_', '')])
```

Comment: do you need to match on the **same** row (in which case it is normal to have an empty DataFrame)? or **any** row?

Comment: sounds like a `merge` job.

Comment: @mozway no, search all rows for every value of ''intersect df. it's ok to have an empty df .

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Then do you want `isin`? `df3[df3['Open Time'].isin(df3['intersect'].str.replace(r'intersect_', ''))]`?

Comment: Did you mean `df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Open Time':Open_Time_s,'intersect':intersect},orient='index').transpose()`?

Comment: @rcriii 1,2 or 0,1 index list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want, just use `.index.tolist()` on the suggestion of @mozway.

Note also I am defining df3 to include `Open_Time_s`.

```
>>> Open_Time_s=['2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00']
>>> intersect=[np.nan,np.nan,'intersect_2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','intersect_2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00']

>>> df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Open Time':Open_Time_s,'intersect':intersect},orient='index').transpose()
>>> df3
                   Open Time                            intersect
0  2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00                                  NaN
1  2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00                                  NaN
2                       None  intersect_2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00
3                       None  intersect_2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00

>>> df3[df3['Open Time'].isin(df3['intersect'].str.replace(r'intersect_', ''))].index.tolist()
[0, 1]
```

With slightly different data

```
>>> Open_Time_s=['2022-04-17 11:05:00+03:00','2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00']
>>> df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Open Time':Open_Time_s,'intersect':intersect},orient='index').transpose()
>>> df3[df3['Open Time'].isin(df3['intersect'].str.replace(r'intersect_', ''))].index.tolist()
[1, 2]
```

Comment: I wouldn't be careful. Expected result to show values, not "nan "

Comment: Can I have a question on this topic?

Comment: this solution does not work in : df['LEVEL']=df['Intersections'].loc[df['Intersections'].isna()==0].apply(lambda x: df[df['Open Time'].isin(x.replace(r'intersect_', ''))].index)

Comment: erorr : only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]

Comment: Yes, because `apply()` passes individual values from a column to the given function, while `isin()` is meant to work on an entire series.

Comment: What is 'LEVEL' meant to contain?